# Solving a linear recurrence with a multiplicity of two

Tags: discrete-mathematics, recurrence-relations

I was given this problem and I am trying to figure out where I go wrong

solve the linear recurrence:

$f(0) = 0$, $f(1) = 0$, $f(2) = 18$,

$f(n) = 3f(n − 1) − 4f(n − 3)$

Here is what I have so far:
Assume: $f(n)=x^n$

$x^n=3x^{n-1}-4x^{n-3}$

$x^3-3x^{2}-4=0$

This factors to:

$(x-2)^2(x+1)$

$x=2$with a multiplicity of $2$ $x=-1$

I think this is where I am having some problems:

$f(n)=ax^n+bnx^n+cx^n$

$f(n)=a2^n+bn2^n+c(-1)^n$

Now I have to solve for $a b c$

***EDIT***

$f(0) = 0$:$f(0)=a2^0+b(0)2^n+c(-1)^0=0$ Simplified: $a-c=0$

$f(1) = 0$: $f(1)=a2^1+b(1)2^n+c(-1)^1=0$ Simplified: $2a+4b-c=0$

$f(2) = 18$: $f(2)=a2^2+b(2)2^n+c(-1)^2=18$ Simplified: $4a+8b+c=18$

$a=6$, $b=-3/2$, $c=6$

can someone tell me if I made a mistake so far because I keep getting the wrong answer

Comment: You should take $(-1)^n$ instead of $n (-1)^n$ as $-1$ does not occur with multiplicity.

Comment: Also it's $n 2^n$, not $n 2$.

Comment: @Nate is that correct now?

Comment: @RobertIsrael are those changes I made correct?

Comment: When you solve for the coefficients you make a couple errors when you plug stuff in.  $(-1)^0 = 1$ and $1*2^1 = 2$.

Answer (score 0):

You are right that you need to solve $f(n)=a2^n+bn2^n+c(−1)^n$

Looks like you had two algebra mistakes.

Your initial conditions are: $f(0)=0, f(1)=0, f(2)=18$

So for $n=0$, (here you had $(-1)^0=-1$ instead of $1$)

$$a + c = 0 \quad \implies \quad a = -c$$

and similarly for $n=1$, (here you had $2^1=4$ instead of $2$)

$$2a+2b-c=2b-3c=0 \quad \implies \quad b = \frac{3}{2}c$$

and for $n=2$,

$$4a+8b+c=9c=18 \quad \implies c=2$$

so we have $(a,b,c)=(-2,3,2)$, so the closed form for the recurrence looks like

$$f(n)=-2^{n+1}+3n2^n+2(−1)^n$$.

Notice this yields $f(0)=0, f(1)=0, f(2)=18, f(3)=54, f(4)=162$ as expected.